# Experiencing frequent "Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Read timed out"

Tags: azure-active-directory, connection-timeout, nimbus-jose-jwt, azure-sdk-for-java

We are running a Spring Boot app on Tomcat 9 and attempting to authenticate with Azure B2C. We are calling

```
     AADJwtBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter b2cConverter
                = new AADJwtBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter();
```

and then presumably the AAD code is procuring the rest of its dependencies. However we are frequently seeing timeouts validating the JWT tokens:

```
29-12-2021|22:09:43.620 tce-test-molina-01 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] ERROR org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage - Forwarding to error page from request [/whoami/] due to exception [An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Read timed out]
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:97)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Read timed out
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:167)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.get(RemoteJWKSet.java:260)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.proc.JWSVerificationKeySelector.selectJWSKeys(JWSVerificationKeySelector.java:157)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.proc.JWSAlgorithmFamilyJWSKeySelector.selectJWSKeys(JWSAlgorithmFamilyJWSKeySelector.java:75)
    at com.azure.spring.aad.AADIssuerJWSKeySelector.selectKeys(AADIssuerJWSKeySelector.java:54)
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.selectKeys(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:281)
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:354)
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:303)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:154)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1374)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:985)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:754)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.getInputStream(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:305)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.retrieveResource(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:257)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:165)
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

This looks very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643595/auth0-couldnt-retrieve-remote-jwk-set-read-timed-out), but I still don't have a solution that will fix this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

- Java 11
- Tomcat 9
- Spring 5.3.8
- Spring Boot 2.5.7
- Spring Security 5.5.4
- Nimbus-Jose-JWT 9.10.1

Answer (score 0):

By default, Resource Server uses connection and socket timeouts which may be too short in some scenarios for coordinating with the authorization server.
Workarounds you can do in codes is that adjust the time-out parameter. Or you can investigate your network environment

NimbusJwtDecoder accepts an instance of RestOperations:

```
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        RestOperations rest = builder
                .setConnectionTimeout(60000)
                .setReadTimeout(60000)
                .build();
    
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri).restOperations(rest).build();
        return jwtDecoder;
```

See [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-timeouts).

For the exception `nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Read timed out.`
Try to `increase  default connection timeout` (in milliseconds) by using `DefaultResourceRetriever`  from their default values (500ms) which is associated in RemoteJWKSet

```
    //Check the default time outs
    System.out.println("Default connect timeout: " + RemoteJWKSet.DEFAULT_HTTP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT + "ms");
    System.out.println("Default read timeout: " + RemoteJWKSet.DEFAULT_HTTP_READ_TIMEOUT + "ms");
    
    int connectTimeoutMs = 1000;
    int readTimeoutMs = 1000;
    new RemoteJWKSet(url, new DefaultResourceRetriever(connectTimeoutMs, readTimeoutMs));
    //increase timeout
```

Try to download the source code for the nimbus library. Modify default timeout parameter and try to prepare custom jar instead of nimbus jar.

[Reference](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/faq#jwk-set-timeout)

**Note:**    `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`
means that the network request timed out, it may not necessarily be the JWT expired or the validation process timed out. The JWT library is trying to request the JWK set and network request must be failing. Please check if the network is consistent.

**References:**

1. [spring-security/issues| github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4474#issuecomment-586578387)
2. [Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set -Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467932/couldnt-retrieve-remote-jwk-set-login-microsoftonline-com)
3. [How to increase RemoteJWKSet cache TTL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409678/how-to-increase-remotejwkset-cache-ttl-in-spring-security-5-2)